# How to use nuget package code inbetween #if DEBUG #endif directives?

Tags: c#, debugging, nuget, lidgren

I'm using the latest .NET core target Lidgren fork: https://github.com/soccermitchy/lidgren-network-gen3 and I'm trying to simulate packet loss / high latency.

There is documentation on how to do this here: https://github.com/lidgren/lidgren-network-gen3/wiki/Lag-Simulation.

This is how I set up my net peer configuration:

```
config = new NetPeerConfiguration(name);
// This line breaks
config.SimulatedLoss = 0.5f;
config.Port = NetConfig.port;
config.MaximumConnections = 200;
config.EnableMessageType(NetIncomingMessageType.ConnectionApproval);
```

The line: `config.SimulatedLoss = 0.5f;` does not work because apparantly `NetPeerConfiguration does not contain a definition for SimulatedLoss`.

When I take a look at the source code: https://github.com/soccermitchy/lidgren-network-gen3/blob/master/Lidgren.Network/NetPeerConfiguration.cs#L468 I see that the SimulatedLoss is between #if DEBUG #endif directives.

How can I run code from NuGet packages that are for debugging only?

I tried enabling a few options in Tools -> Debug and a few other things but I really can't find an answer anywhere.

I apologize in advance if this question has already been asked multiple times before.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is nothing you can do from the outside. If the nuget package you got was not compiled with the DEBUG flag, that code is not in there.

You will have to find a package that was compiled as debug, or compile the library yourself as debug.

Comment: That makes perfect sense, thank you. I will try to build it myself then. Will accept this as the answer in a few minutes.